# hold versions of doc file with mssql blob file

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ms-word, blob

we can assume the user is working with Ms Word files.

After the user chooses a file, the software needs to store it.
That is easy, with Delphi blob and MsSql image.

Now lets say the user wants to edit the file, 
could you suggest a simple solution, that will open the file in Ms Word, allow edit, and then save the changes to the image?

It would be better if old version could be kept, like svn.

Any component that you could suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copy the blob out to a temp file:
2. C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Temp\2011112_1115112.doc

   or

   wherever windows wants you to store temp files for this user.
3. Launch WinWord on that file,
4. waiting on the program to finish.
5. When they're done, copy it back.

For multi-user situations, you'll need exclusive access.  WinWord usually figures that out when you're sharing files.  But in this case, you'll have to simulate it, perhaps with a field on the table row to reserve/release the document for read/write access.

Comment: how do the process know the program(word) had finished?

Comment: See here [how-to-tell-when-an-external-application-ends-in-delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102890/how-to-tell-when-an-external-application-ends-in-delphi)